# Get list from Animation Nodes using console

Tags: python, animation-nodes

Is it possible to get the outputs of a node from the Blender console?
For example, I can acces to this expression from Animation Nodes in the Blender console:

```
bpy.data.node_groups['NodeTree'].nodes["Expression.001"]
```

But I do not find a method to get the list from the console in order to be used in a custom addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Data Interface` node to export data outside AN.

[image]

Comment: It is a good solution. My solution was to write a script at the ouput of the expression that fill a collection property declared in the addon. The collection type is a property group with a vector property. So, each item has a float vector property.